# Why is my HTML form being submitted?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form with 1 field. I want that when the user `clicks` or hits `enter` it should call a JavaScript function that will do validation and either display an error message or submit the form.

However, when hitting `enter` it submits the form regardless. (So far in my JavaScript validation function I only have `alert ("Hello World")`)

```
<form  action="add-another-number-to-dnc.cshtml" method="post" id="addDNCform">
    <h4>Enter 10-digit phone number without dashes, dots or parenthesis</h4> 
    <input type="text" name="pn" required placeholder="phone number" 
        title="Phone Number to Add to Do-Not-Call List" 
        onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnVldt').click()"/> <!-- all this is to treat [Enter] as a click -->
    <input id="btnVldt" type="button" value="Add Number to Do Not Call list" onclick="submitDNC()"/>
</form>
```

I added all the page code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LTckU/2/) where you can test and verify that:

- when clicking on the button, it correctly doesn't submit the form
- when hitting `enter` it gives you an Error 404 which must mean, it's trying to load the page.

**Added this:**

Actually, if I use `submit` instead of `button`, it doesn't work also when clicking. However, in `jsFiddle` it seems to work.

Comment: Hmm a `type` of `button` should not submit.  What browser is this?  You can try changing your code to: `submitDNC(); return false;`

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Praveen's answer here, I'm going to write the JavaScript "unobtrusively" to further separate function, presentation, and content:

### HTML

```
<form action="add-another-number-to-dnc.cshtml" method="post" id="addDNCform">
    <h4>Enter 10-digit phone number without dashes, dots or parenthesis</h4> 
    <input type="text" name="pn" required placeholder="phone number"  title="Phone Number to Add to Do-Not-Call List" />
    <button type='submit'>Add Number to Do Not Call list"</button>
</form>
```

### (X)HTML5

Assuming that you want a 10-digit number in the box (numeric characters only), we can also use the `pattern` attribute on the `<input>` element in HTML5 as a form of validation for newer browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE10, Opera):

```
<form action="add-another-number-to-dnc.cshtml" method="post" id="addDNCform">
    <h4>Enter 10-digit phone number without dashes, dots or parenthesis</h4> 
    <input type="text" name="pn" required placeholder="phone number" title="Phone Number to Add to Do-Not-Call List" pattern="[0-9]{10}" />
    <button type='submit'>Add Number to Do Not Call list"</button>
</form>
```

### JavaScript (place inside `<script>` tags somewhere on the page)

```
function submitDNC(event) {
    var valid = false;

    alert('Hello world');
    // your validation logic goes here, sets valid to TRUE if it's valid

    if(!valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

document.getElementById('addDNCform').addEventListener( 'submit', submitDNC, false );
```

No need to do any synthetic button clicking if all you're trying to do is validate upon form submission. Pretty soon with HTML5 we might not even need JavaScript for this, depending on what your validation logic is.

Comment: `+1` for your explanation! :)

Comment: rink, it's still being submitted. Is it because I have some server-side code? But doesn't that execute when the page is loaded? I posted all the code (not updated with your function) in [jsFiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/LTckU)

Comment: @Amarundo The server side code that is on the page should be executed before the page is sent to the browser. Try implementing my function and see if that works.

Comment: I'm not sure, it's working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5mMmZ/ Have you checked Firebug/IE Developer Tools/Chrome Developer to see if any error comes up?

Comment: I did, but, it's my first time doing that, and I'm not sure what to look for. Using chrome.

Comment: I've been busy at work with other pressing issues. Will check next week. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your `submitDNC()` function, give a `return false;`.

```
function submitDNC()
{
    alert("Hello World!");
    return false;
}
```

Another thing is, change your `input` type from `button` to `submit`. Use:

```
<input id="btnVldt" type="submit"
       value="Add Number to Do Not Call list" onclick="return submitDNC();" />
```

#### Explanation

The return value of an event handler determines whether or not the default browser behaviour should take place as well. In the case of clicking on links, this would be following the link, but the difference is most noticeable in form submit handlers, where you can cancel a form submission if the user has made a mistake entering the information.

---

#### Another Option

As [Rink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404623/rink-attendant-6) says, `return false;` is overkill for something that can and should be handled by `preventDefault()`. So, you can do this way, by using unobtrusive JavaScript.

```
function submitDNC()
{
    alert("Hello World!");
    var e = window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, but `return false;` is overkill for something that can and should be handled by `preventDefault()` (i.e. preventing the default action of submitting the form): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: Wouldn't you need: `onclick="return submitDNC()"`

Comment: @MikeChristensen Just missed. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Can you check if my answer is right, am not sure about it. If possible, can you correct it?

Comment: After I posted here, I did a `.reset()` and that prevented the submission, but it cleared the user's input which is annoying if the guy just missed a digit or something. I'll try `return false`, because I don't know where to type the `preventDefault()` thing.

Comment: @Amarundo `.reset()` is for **clearing the forms**, which you don't need here. Yup, please lemme know if it works. :)

Comment: Thanks, now I know where to type `preventDefault()`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I submitted my own answer expanding upon yours, that's how I use `preventDefault()` there. I had to think a bit as I had to try to refrain from using jQuery here :D

Comment: @PraveenKumar neither option is working. The form `action` which is to reload the same page `add-another-number-to-dnc` is being triggered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Amarundo Can you post the full HTML and JavaScript code by editing your question? Or, best, can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent submit when pressing ENTER, use this piece of code:

```
function checkEnter(e){
    e = e || event;
    var txtArea = /textarea/i.test((e.target || e.srcElement).tagName);
    return txtArea || (e.keyCode || e.which || e.charCode || 0) !== 13;
}
```

then, add the handler to the `form`:

```
document.querySelector('form').onkeypress = checkEnter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the  to a Submit, although this isn't what's getting you in trouble here.  For some odd reason browser programmers thought it was a good idea to code so that browsers assume buttons within forms submit them.  You'll want to change onkeypress to call a function.  In that function do something like this:

```
function keyPressPhone() {
  if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
    document.getElementById("addDNCform").submit();
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false; // somehow prevents the form from being submitted
  }
}
```